# WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I can't understand the WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS variable in Pycharm Python console configuration.

What is it? and how does it become my project path?

in the last line of the screenshot, we can see the message `sys.path.extend([])` in the IPython console which indicates that it got my working dir successfully:

[image]

This is the WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS in the start script section in Pycharm Python console configuration which has a line of `sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])`

[image]

Comment: because my project root is my content root, "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH"  adds my project root to PYTHONPATH.
But WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS is also my project root and adds to the sys.path

Comment: No, I just wanna know what the WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS exactly is? I can't find it in Pycharm or environment variables.

Comment: You mean where it comes from? The value can be seen in the first image you attached. The "working dir" is the content/source root, and the `PYTHONPATH` is a variable integrated into the Python install

Comment: If you must know, it's added from Java code. http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=idea/community.git;a=blob;f=python/src/com/jetbrains/python/console/RunPythonConsoleAction.java;h=27b60918deb0e3c5ce474c1840965c5abf187eaf;hb=265a76354456ebdd5392076716f3268bc5248888#l53

Comment: That's super weird, some uncustomizable variable, added internally...